# how do i set the first page of my site in drupal 6?

Tags: views

I am new to drupal.

I started ctreaing site but facing problem in

how do set my first page in drupal

eg:

when user type

www.mysite.com

he should redirect to first page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: admin/settings/site-information. In the section of "DEFAULT FRONT PAGE" you can set a default page for you site. (The page for default is node.)

If you have another page that you want to become in the default page, only copy the url of the page and put this in "DEFAULT FRONT PAGE."

Answer (score 1):

Have you been to /admin/settings/site-information and set the homepage from there? At the bottom put the node address into Default Front Page field, something like node/1 (or whatever node number you want the front page to be)